# Ruby on Rails 6 PUT json parameters are not set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a very simple Rails 6 controller called BlogsController, there is UPDATE action, called update. When I try to submit json using postman, it returns 400 Bad Request, in the logs I find that there is ONLY ONE ??? parameter id, my json content is ignored. This is very basic thing that should work and it doesn't. It confuses me. Please help.

This is controller code:

```
class BlogsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
  before_action :set_blog, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]

  # GET /blogs or /blogs.json
  def index
    @blogs = Blog.all
  end

  # GET /blogs/1 or /blogs/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /blogs/new
  def new
    @blog = Blog.new
  end

  # GET /blogs/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /blogs or /blogs.json
  def create
    @blog = Blog.new(blog_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @blog.save
        format.html { redirect_to @blog, notice: "Blog was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @blog }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @blog.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /blogs/1 or /blogs/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @blog.update(blog_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @blog, notice: "Blog was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @blog }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @blog.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /blogs/1 or /blogs/1.json
  def destroy
    @blog.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to blogs_url, notice: "Blog was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_blog
      @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def blog_params
      params.require(:blog).permit(:title, :content)
    end
end
```

I do `PUT` `json` to `/blogs/1` with Content-Type header set to application/json

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

the item to update looks like this:

```
{ "blog": {"id":1,"title":"Blog one","content":"Blog 1 Test Sem"} }
```

error message in the logs looks like this:

```
2 [2] Started PUT "/blogs/1" for 54.86.50.139 at 2021-12-02 10:38:14 +0000
2 [2] Processing by BlogsController#update as JSON
2 [2]   Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
2 heroku[router]: at=info method=PUT path="/blogs/1" host=ror-backend-angular-13.herokuapp.com request_id=2f1982a8-bbe1-41b0-bb3c-09b7e3db7caa fwd="54.86.50.139" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7ms status=400 bytes=223 protocol=https
2 [2] Completed 400 Bad Request in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.9ms | Allocations: 441)
2 FATAL -- : [2]
2 [2] ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: blog
2: Did you mean?  action
2: controller
2: id):
2: [2]
2: [2] app/controllers/blogs_controller.rb:68:in `blog_params'
2 [2] app/controllers/blogs_controller.rb:41:in `block in update'
2 [2] app/controllers/blogs_controller.rb:40:in `update'
```

as you can see in the logs, there is only one parsed parameter: `{"id"=>"1"}` . Why the `JSON` content body is ignored? This is something completely crazy, it is killing me.

Comment: My protip is to write an integration test (or request spec if you're using RSpec) - instead of using Postman. That way you can share it with us and we can reproduce the results. It also means that you're spending your time safeguarding against future regressions instead of getting your postman/curl inputs just right which is wasted time. 99% of the time its just simple user error and what you're doing on your end is a black box to us.

Comment: There is also two little unidiomatic things here - [PATCH is the primary method for updates since way back in 2012](https://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/2/26/edge-rails-patch-is-the-new-primary-http-method-for-updates/) but Rails still generates PUT routes for backwards compatibility and you don't need to / want to pass the id in the request body since its a part of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Postman but I can help you using cURL to submit JSON data to your Rails API. Please find the instructions below:

To send JSON the first step is to put the data (to be sent to the API) in its JSON format in a file say `my_data.json` and save it to a location say `/home/jignesh` and then use the following cURL URL to send the request**:

```
curl -X PUT -H "Content-type: application/json" --data-binary @/home/jignesh/my_data.json "http://<API_URL>/blogs/<BLOG_ID>"
```

Answer (score -1):

You're PUTting to the `blogs/1` endpoint, not `blogs/1.json`, according to the log. The code is ignoring the params (perhaps they're not being sent properly by Postman - you've not indicated what you've done on that end - but certainly they're ignored!). My assumption is that, by PUTting to `blogs/1` you code is taking it as a PUT to `blogs` with the parameter `1` taken from the URL. The body of your request is being ignored.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. Whether I PUT to blogs/1 or blogs/1.json makes no difference, same error is thrown.

Comment: OK, so if you use byebug (or whatever) at the top of your controller, what do the parameters look like there. (Rather than relying on the log.) Because it's getting that `1` from somewhere. What happens if you PUT to `blogs/2` with the same JSON message?

Comment: If you look at the log Rails is clearly treating the request as JSON. I would assume that correct content type is being sent. Using an extension is only one way of setting the reqeust format.